How can I specify the path when loading the spacy model?
I've downloaded the spacy model using:
$ python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
From the terminal I am able to load the model and get its path:
>>> import spacy
>>> model = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
>>> model._path
PosixPath('/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/en_core_web_md/en_core_web_md-2.2.5')

The problem is when I try to load the model from a notebook running in Azure ML studio, I can't load the model and I get an error:
from pathlib import Path
import spacy

# Specify the path to the directory containing the model
directory_path = "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/en_core_web_md"

# Load the model using spacy.load() function
nlp = spacy.load(directory_path)

OSError: [E053] Could not read config file from /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/en_core_web_md/config.cfg

How can I go about downloading spacy to a specific directory and loading it from there?
